# Are these definitions of a prime ideal equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I just noticed I have three different definitions of a prime ideal in my notes. So are these definitions equivalent? Are they all correct...I have feeling I might have taken something down wrong.

Let $I$ be an ideal in a commutative ring $R$.

$I$ is prime if -

- $a, b \in R$ with $a,b \notin I$ then $a \cdot b \notin I$
- $a, b \in I$ then $a\cdot b \notin I$
- $a, b \in I$ then either $a \in I$ or $b \in I$

Comment: You seem to be putting commas where you mean multiplication.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the second one.

Comment: The second one is false big time

Comment: And change the commas in the third  one.

Comment: I edited that before you wrote, @CameronBuie   :)

Comment: @Don: Oops! Now I see it (upon refreshing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition for an ideal $I$ of the *commutative* ring $R$ to be prime is

> for all $a,b\in R$, if $ab\in I$, then $a\in I$ or $b\in I$

The condition

> for all $a,b\in R$, if $a\notin I$ and $b\notin I$, then $ab\notin I$

is just a reformulation of the above condition, using the fact that $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to $(\text{not }Q)\implies (\text{not }P)$.

Your second condition is false for any ideal: if $a,b\in I$, then clearly $ab\in I$: it suffices that *one* of $a$ and $b$ belongs to $I$ in order that $ab\in I$.

Your third condition is the first I gave provided we remove the comma; saying $a,b\in I$ is just an abbreviation for “$a\in I$ and $b\in I$”, so it wouldn't define anything special.

Answer (score 2):

Your third condition should read that $I$ is prime if for $a,b\in R$ with $a\cdot b \in I,$ we have $a \in I$ or $b \in I.$

Your second version is completely false. (In fact, for *any* ideal $I,$ if $a,b\in I$ then $a\cdot b\in I$.) The other two are simply contrapositives.